# Java how create blank project from command line

Tags: java, maven

I've just started to learn Java but I'd like to do most of commands via terminal on Linux.

Is it possible to create new Java project just from terminal? It would be convinient for me to test some code right on my VDS.

Is there any command like this `mvn create my-app` insted of cloning blank project from some git repo?

For now every Google's searching result is about "how to **run**..**build**..**compile**"..e.t.c. but not how to **create** a new project.

Comment: Read https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Comment: @Jens, thanks! That's what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use maven archetype plugin. An example from mavens website:

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`